# Configuring AMD RX 580 on Fedora 34

Tags: linux, fedora, hardware, amd

I have ASUS AMD RX 580 on Fedora 34 system. This series of video cards have problems with very high default core frequency and power limits. Video core has normal temperature, but some small components overheat. It cause my video card toggle protective mode and shutdowns, when I run any game with graphics a bit more beautiful than Dwarf Fortress ;). I have been looking for this problem for very long time. When I had windows 10 I fix it by configuring maximal GPU frequency and power limit in AMD Radeon Software. Now I switched to Fedora and I can't to install this application.

Have I any way to fix this problem on Fedora 34? For example, can I install some utility like AMD Radeon Software or MSI Afterburner for linux? May be I can to configure my graphics card in console?

Comment: https://wiki.archlinux.org/title/AMDGPU#GUI

Answer (score 0):

It shall be possible with the amdgpu driver and fairly recent kernels.
The tuning is usually done via sysfs settings, additions to kernel cmdline
and optional driver parameters (see `modinfo amdgpu` for example).
Here is a similar issue explained in detail:
[Reduce AMD GPU Wattage](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/620072/reduce-amd-gpu-wattage)

Answer (score 0):

Try [`radeon-profile`](https://github.com/marazmista/radeon-profile), it's a GUI to set `amdgpu` driver options and monitor gpu status.

[image: Radeon Profile]